# Image tracking pixel only fire on iphone

Tags: html, tracking

say I have a tracking pixel in my html

```
<img src="someurl.com" >
```

How can I get it to only fire on say IPhone 6?  I have tried giving the image an inline style to display none, and then display block in a media query, but that does not seem to work.  Is there a way around this?

Thanks

**Update**

```
<style>
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) {
    .tracking-img{
        display:block!important;
    }
}
</style>
```

And then at the bottom of my body I have

```
<img class="tracking-img" style="display:none;" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?tracking_stuff" />
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I have updated the OP.  This is in an email hence the style tags